# Access First Two Values of any Array made by Split?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

Suppose I have to access a some pattern of digit using javascript. Please have a look.

For Example :: Pattern needed :: Fomat - $12.00 only

If user enters the value 123.12 => Output = $123.12

If user enters the value 123.1 => Output = $123.10

If user enters the value 123.1237 => Output = $123.12 :: Here I am unable to get the first two element of second array having value as 1237.

Thanks

Comment: How about 1234.12 or 123.56? BTW, there is a rails function `number_to_currency(1234.56)` could do the trick. Is it have to done in javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `'123.1237` as a string `input`, then `input.split('.')` would give you an array with two strings `123` and `1237`. Thus what you really want to do is sub-string the second string to get the first two characters:

`1237`.subsring(0, 2);

Comment: No problem but @strager had an answer which you should probably use in your code in the long run.

Answer (score 3):

Why not:

```
var number = 123.1237;
var dollarAmount = number.toFixed(2);
console.log(dollarAmount);
```

Nasty string manipulation is not the answer here.